# ANTLR grammar ambiguity

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Given the following ANTLR 3 grammar:

```
statement1 : CHAR_KEYWORD;
statement2 : DIGIT_KEYWORD (COLON_KEYWORD DIGIT_KEYWORD)?;

COLON_KEYWORD : ':';
DIGIT_KEYWORD : '0'..'9';
CHAR_KEYWORD : 'a'..'z' | COLON_KEYWORD;
```

When parsing the following text:

```
1
```

The rule *statement2* picks up this text. This is good. However, if one has the following text now:

```
1:2
```

The rule *statement2* does not pick up this text and gives an error. This is because ":" is matched by CHAR_KEYWORD which is not part of the rule. If one removes the COLON_KEYWORD from the CHAR_KEYWORD, rule *statement2* works fine except that rule *statement1* does not work as required now. How can this grammar be refactored so that both rules *statement1* and *statement2* work as expected? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the COLON_KEYWORD alt from CHAR_KEYWORD and instead add it as alt to statement1.

```
statement1 : CHAR_KEYWORD | COLON_KEYWORD;
statement2 : DIGIT_KEYWORD (COLON_KEYWORD DIGIT_KEYWORD)?;

COLON_KEYWORD : ':';
DIGIT_KEYWORD : '0'..'9';
CHAR_KEYWORD : 'a'..'z';
```